# JDOM parses much slower than DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, jdom

I have 2 methods to parse the same XML document using `DOM` and `JDOM`. I expected `JDOM` runs faster and consumes less memory than `DOM` but actually `JDOM` run several times slower and consumed much much more memory in my benchmark. I'm using JMH as the benchmarking framework.

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime) 
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 1, time = 200, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MyBenchmark {

    @Param({"1.xml"})
    public String xml;

    @Benchmark 
    public void DOM(){

        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File(xml);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = 
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    @Benchmark 
    public void JDOM(){
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File(xml);

        try {
            Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
            System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

DOM results

```
Benchmark                                         (xml)  Mode  Cnt         Score          Error   Units
MyBenchmark.DOM                                   1.xml    ss   10       126.823 ±       16.821   ms/op
MyBenchmark.DOM:·gc.alloc.rate                    1.xml    ss   10        92.618 ±        2.481  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.DOM:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               1.xml    ss   10  60869076.800 ±      130.041    B/op
```

JDOM2 results

```
Benchmark                                          (xml)  Mode  Cnt           Score           Error   Units
MyBenchmark.JDOM                                   1.xml    ss   10         789.941 ±        81.293   ms/op
MyBenchmark.JDOM:·gc.alloc.rate                    1.xml    ss   10        2248.753 ±       141.240  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.JDOM:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               1.xml    ss   10  3037712408.000 ±         0.001    B/op
```

The document has 12MB in size and contains 192,000 elements. Below is the structure of the XML document, the document has 38,400 level 1 elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <level_1 Element_Number="1">
      <level_2 Attribute_Level_2="Attribute_Level_2">
         <level_3_1 Attribute_Level_3="Attribute_Level_3">test</level_3_1>
         <level_3_2 Attribute_Level_3="Attribute_Level_3">test</level_3_2>
         <level_3_3 Attribute_Level_3="Attribute_Level_3">test</level_3_3>
      </level_2>
   </level_1>
   <level_1 Element_Number="2">
      <level_2 Attribute_Level_2="Attribute_Level_2">
         <level_3_1 Attribute_Level_3="Attribute_Level_3">test</level_3_1>
         <level_3_2 Attribute_Level_3="Attribute_Level_3">test</level_3_2>
         <level_3_3 Attribute_Level_3="Attribute_Level_3">test</level_3_3>
      </level_2>
   </level_1>
```

Can anyone explain this? I'm using JDOM 2.0.2 anyway.

**Edit:** DOM vs JDOM benchmarks for small documents (5000 to 25,000 elements)
[image]

Comment: You parsed it one time, 1000 times ?

Comment: I parse the document 100 times.

Comment: Is your loop including the `SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();` and reading the file with `new File` or just the very last step of parsing the document ?

Comment: Actually there's no loop, I used `@Param` in JMH to pass XML document to the method.

Comment: Each parser has a cost to startup, so if some objects should can be reused you are not measuring the real-life performance of these libraries. Also as @Michael Kay stated you may have a case for which one parser is better than the other, but it does not say one parser is always better.

Comment: I'm not reusing the XML document for the test because both JDOM and DOM have Document that would cause conflict when parsing together at the same time. Anyway, what do you mean by the cost to startup?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't match my experience. See Appendix A of http://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2018mhk.pdf where I reported identical times for parsing/tree-building for DOM and JDOM2. That doesn't mean your figures are wrong, of course, it just means there is something about them that is specific to what you were measuring that might not extrapolate to a different scenario.

But why are you so coy about giving us actual numbers? What was the document size, what were the actual measurements? I was measuring a 10Mb XMark source document: what were you measuring?

**==UPDATE==**

I have now realised that I am not building the JDOM2 tree using the tree builder supplied with JDOM2, I am building it with Saxon's JDOM2 tree builder. So I changed it to use the JDOM2 builder - and it now goes a little faster: between 89.1 and 91.2ms, compared with 111.8ms for DOM.

But I'm also using Saxon's DOM builder rather than the native one. So let's change that too. The time for DOM now comes down to 74ms, which is fairly comparable with your figures.

I think (from what I have read) that the reason the DOM builder is faster is that it uses lazy building techniques: that is, it leaves some of the work to be done later, on first access to the data. This is why read-access to the DOM is not thread-safe; even though you are only using read methods at the API level, they are causing internal updates to the stored tree.

Comment: Hi Michael, I added the benchmark results. Can you have a look at that?

Comment: The difference in memory usage is ridiculous. I think it would be a good idea to publish the code you used for benchmarking so we can see if other people can reproduce the results. Your measurement for DOM aligns quite closely with mine; your measurement for JDOM2 is way different.

Comment: I added the code I used to measure. I also benchmarked DOM4J and it actually parsed slower than DOM and consumed slightly more memory which I did not expect. Can you explain why DOM is so efficient in term of parsing the entire DOM tree into memory?

Comment: I haven't succeeded in getting JMH to run in my development environment, but I've rerun my measurements under my own benchmarking framework and confirmed my results: DOM 105ms, JDOM 108ms.

Comment: Do you use the same JDOM set up as mine? `SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File(xml);`

Comment: I added 2 graphs of DOM vs JDOM performances, JDOM seems way more expensive than DOM, however.

Comment: I constructed a test data file with the same structure as yours (32K level-1 elements) and this time JDOM was faster: DOM 111.8ms, JDOM2 94.7ms. I'm afraid this is entirely typical of exercises like this: it's very easy for two people apparently measuring the same thing to get quite different answers because of some hard-to-identify difference in the benchmarks.